# Why does this magnet not damage electronics?

Tags: electromagnetism, electronics

The "magic cellphone holder" found at [this link](http://www.scosche.com/mmsurface) works by taking advantage of a magnet and a metal plate that you stick to your phone.

Why does the magnet not damage the electronic components of the cell phone?

Magnets do damage electronics, correct?

Answer (score 2):

Electronics is mostly insensitive to static magnetic fields of that strength. The only serious damage that I would expect for electronic circuits is to switching power supplies (and circuits that are being powered by it) in the case that an inductor core gets saturated. In practice I have been debugging electronics for something like 40 years and I have not seen a single case like that, so I would put even this mechanism into the "hypothetical" bin. Color CRT tubes may have suffered reversible damage (but they are gone) and some photomultiplier tubes may be irreversibly damaged, but you don't have those around.

I have seen one case of a malfunction because a small signal relays was triggered by a magnetic component that was mounted too close. The effect was sporadic and harmless, but it could have been serious, if the relays had been used in a safety or power circuit.